# Anyone used the Ruby Nettica gem?

Tags: ruby, dns

Has anyone used the Ruby Nettica gem to add an A-record to their DNS file on Nettica?

I am continually getting 404 errors but I know that my user/pass creds are correct and I know the domain exists!

Thanks for any help.

Chad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just in, you need to buy their bulk DNS service in order to get the AddRecord to work.....